# QtIFW - UrlQueryString fails with Unexpected element

Tags: xml, qt, qt-installer

In the Installer documentation I found an element called `UrlQueryString` (It is listed in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-globalconfig.html#summary-of-configuration-file-elements)). But if I try to use it, the `binarycreator` fails with the following error:

```
Caught exception: Error in ./config/config.xml, line 20, column 17: Unexpected element 'UrlQueryString'.
```

My `config.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    <Name>MyApp</Name>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Title>MyApp Installer</Title>
    <Publisher>Me</Publisher>
    <StartMenuDir>MyApp</StartMenuDir>
    <TargetDir>@HomeDir@/AppData/Local/MyApp</TargetDir>
    <AdminTargetDir>@ApplicationsDir@/MyApp</AdminTargetDir>
    <RunProgram>MyApp</RunProgram>
    <AllowSpaceInPath>true</AllowSpaceInPath>
    <AllowNonAsciiCharacters>true</AllowNonAsciiCharacters>
    <RemoteRepositories>
        <Repository>
            <Url>http://example.com/repositories/MyApp</Url>
            <Enabled>1</Enabled>
            <DisplayName>MyApp Repository</DisplayName>
        </Repository>
    </RemoteRepositories>
    <UrlQueryString>os=win</UrlQueryString>
    <ControlScript>autoNextControl.js</ControlScript>
</Installer>
```

Am I using the `UrlQueryString` wrong? I tried to place it into `Repository` too, but it generates the same error with different lines.

I am using the 2.0.1 precompiled version of the framwork, the same the documentation was created for, on windows (but later an mac/x11 too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Instead of adding the url inside of the xml-file, you can just add it in the controller script:

```
installer.setValue("UrlQueryString", "os=win");
```

This works fine